# Как равномерно растянуть элементы в StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

В общем, есть такой StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="Путь к БД" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding PathToDb, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             IsEnabled="False" />
    <Button Content="..." />
</StackPanel>
```

Он помещен внутрь `Grid'a`.

Проблема в том, что у меня не получается сделать так, что бы элементы равномерно заняли ячейку Grid'a.

Вот такая вот хрень получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя хочу, что бы не было таких отсупов, ведь кнопка справа имеет константную ширину.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду заполнить всю ширину, то StackPanel так не умеет (у нее другая задача), используйте другую панель, например DockPanel или Grid

Comment: Ну и желательно поместить в вопрос эскиз того, что хотите получить

Comment: @АндрейNOP, похоже грид придется делать. Я приложил пример с док панелью...

Comment: Покажите скетч, какой именно вы хотите layout.

Answer (score 1):

`StackPanel` работает по принципу: в направлении компоновки (в вашем случае оно горизонтальное) выделяем минимально необходимое пространство, в ортогональном ему направлении — всё доступное, поэтому ваша задача не решается с помощью `StackPanel` в принципе.

Используйте другую панель, например, `Grid`:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Путь к БД" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" IsEnabled="False"
             Text="{Binding PathToDb, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="..." />
</Grid>
```

Либо `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock Text="Путь к БД" />
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="..." />
    <TextBox Margin="5,0" IsEnabled="False"
             Text="{Binding PathToDb, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: А не `UniformGrid`?

Comment: Ну автор эскиз того что хочет получить не показал, поэтому я предположил, что растянуть надо именно TextBox :)